# Редактирование элемента listview с помощью диалога

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment, dialogfragment, android-context-menu

Имеется фрагмент с listview, который выводит записи из БД. Необходимо настроить возможность редактирования элемента listView. То есть длительное нажатие на элемент, выход диалога, в котором готовы 2 edittext и 1 spinner. Заполняем данные и выбираем из спиннера, и эти данные встают на место старых данных.

Класс фрагмента CountingFragment

```
public class CountingFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> { 

private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1; //ВСЕГДА 1, т.к. пункты в меню начинаются с 1 итема
private static final int CM_EDIT_ID = 2; //редактирование итема

public static final int COUNT_LOADER = 2; 

private final int UPDATE_LIST = 1; //переменная для результата добавление записи
private final int EDIT_LIST = 2; //переменная для результата редактирования записи

ListView lvData;
DB db;
private CursorCountingAdapter scAdapter;
Button addCount;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counting, container, false);

    lvData = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lvDataCount);

    db = new DB(getActivity());
    db.open();

    scAdapter = new CursorCountingAdapter(getActivity(), null);

    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter); 
    registerForContextMenu(lvData);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);

    lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {


            boolean isCheck = scAdapter.isChecked();

            db.changeChecked(id, isCheck ? 0 : 1);

                  getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(COUNT_LOADER).forceLoad();
        }
    });

    addCount = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_count_but);
    addCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            String name = getArguments().getString("name");
            arguments.putString("name", name);
            dialog.setArguments(arguments);
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CountingFragment.this, UPDATE_LIST);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom");

        }
    });

    Button questionBut = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.question_but);
    questionBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            QuestDialogFragment questDialogFragment = new QuestDialogFragment();
            questDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "quest");
        }
    });

    return v;

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case UPDATE_LIST: getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);
            break;
        case EDIT_LIST: getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() { //правильно обновляются старые данные при переключении между фрагментами
    super.onStart();
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);

}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
    menu.add(0, CM_EDIT_ID, 0, R.string.edit_record);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
    long id = acmi.id;
    int position = acmi.position;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CM_DELETE_ID:
            // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
            db.delRec(id);
            // получаем новый курсор с данными
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(COUNT_LOADER).forceLoad();
            return true;

        case CM_EDIT_ID:

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lvData.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String ingTextDialog = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.COLUMN_INGR));
            String valTextDialog = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.COLUMN_VAL));
            String uniTextDialog = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.COLUMN_UNI));

            EditCountDialog editCountDialog = new EditCountDialog();

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

            arguments.putString("ing", ingTextDialog);
            arguments.putString("val", valTextDialog);
            arguments.putString("uni", uniTextDialog);
            arguments.putLong("id", id);

            editCountDialog.setTargetFragment(CountingFragment.this, EDIT_LIST);

            editCountDialog.setArguments(arguments);

            editCountDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "edit");
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(COUNT_LOADER).forceLoad();


            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String name = getArguments().getString("name"); //строка для получения аргументов создается в onCreateLoader
    return new CursorLoaderCount(getActivity(), db, id, name);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}

static class CursorLoaderCount extends CursorLoader {
    Cursor cursor;
    final int LoaderId;
    DB db;
    String name;

    public CursorLoaderCount(Context context, DB db, int id, String name) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
        LoaderId = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {

        switch (LoaderId){

            case COUNT_LOADER:
                cursor = db.getIngrNew(name);
                break;
        }

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

}

В контекстном меню достал необходимые данные из курсора и передал через setArguments в класс диалога

```
public class EditCountDialog extends DialogFragment {

String ing;
String val;
String uni;
long index;

EditText dialogIngredients;
EditText dialogZnachenie;
Spinner dialogUnits;

@NonNull
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ing = getArguments().getString("ing");
    val = getArguments().getString("val");
    uni = getArguments().getString("uni");
    index = getArguments().getLong("id");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

    dialogIngredients = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ingredientsEdit);
    dialogZnachenie = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_znachenieEdit);
    dialogUnits = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_units_spinner);

    dialogIngredients.setText(ing);
    dialogZnachenie.setText(val);


    return builder
            .setTitle("Редактировать " + ing + " " + val + " " + uni)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_question)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", null)
            .setPositiveButton("Сохранить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {

                    DB db = new DB(getActivity());
                    db.open();
                    db.editRec(index, dialogIngredients.getText().toString(),
                            dialogZnachenie.getText().toString(),
                            dialogUnits.getSelectedItem().toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), dialogIngredients.getText().toString() + " " +
                            dialogZnachenie.getText().toString() + " " +
                            dialogUnits.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    update();
                }
            })
            .create();
}

public void update(){
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
}
}
```

С помощью Toast проверил, дошли ли данные до класса диалога - дошли успешно. Далее пытаюсь в БД создать метод, который обновит выбранную запись

Класс БД

```
public class DB {

        private static final String DB_NAME = "mealhbhybl"; 
        private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; 
        private static final String DB_TABLE = "myMeals";

        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_MEAL = "mealing";
        public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img";
        public static final String COLUMN_INGR = "ingr";
        public static final String COLUMN_VAL = "val";
        public static final String COLUMN_UNI = "uni";
        public static final String COLUMN_IMGV3 = "img3";
        public static final String COLUMN_CHEKBOX = "myCheck";

        private static final String DB_CREATE =
                "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                        COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        COLUMN_IMG + " integer, " +
                        COLUMN_MEAL + " text, " +
                        COLUMN_IMGV3 + " integer, " +
                        COLUMN_INGR + " text, " +
                        COLUMN_VAL + " text, " +
                        COLUMN_UNI + " text, " +
                        COLUMN_CHEKBOX + " integer" +
                        ");";

        private final Context mCtx;


        private DBHelper mDBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

        public DB(Context ctx) {
            mCtx = ctx;
        }

        public void changeChecked (long id, int check){

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COLUMN_CHEKBOX, check);
            mDB.update(DB_TABLE, contentValues, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);

        }


        // открыть подключение
        public void open() {
            mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        // закрыть подключение
        public void close() {
            if (mDBHelper != null) mDBHelper.close();
        }

        // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
        public Cursor getAllData() {
            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }


        public Cursor getMeal () {
            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_MEAL, COLUMN_IMGV3}, null, null, COLUMN_MEAL, null, null);
        }

    public Cursor getIngrNew (String name) {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{String.valueOf(COLUMN_CHEKBOX), COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, DB.COLUMN_MEAL + " = ?", new String[]{name}, null, null, null);
    }

    public int delMeal (String name) {
        return mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, DB.COLUMN_MEAL + " = ?", new String[]{name});
    }

    // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
        public void addRec(int img, int img3, String mealing, String ingr, String val, String uni, int checkbox) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(COLUMN_UNI, uni);
            cv.put(COLUMN_VAL, val);
            cv.put(COLUMN_INGR, ingr);
            cv.put(COLUMN_MEAL, mealing);
            cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
            cv.put(COLUMN_IMGV3, img3);
            cv.put(COLUMN_CHEKBOX, checkbox);

            mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
        }

        public void editRec(long id, String ingr, String val, String uni){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_INGR, ingr);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_VAL, val);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_UNI, uni);
        mDB.update(DB_TABLE, contentValues, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);

        }

        // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
        public void delRec(long id) {
            mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
        }

        // класс по созданию и управлению БД
        public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                            int version) {
                super(context, name, factory, version);
            }

            // создаем и заполняем БД
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
            }

        }

    }
```

И в итоге при редактировании запись остается прежней. Не понимаю, где ошибся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что в setArguments при передаче данных я передавал position, а нужно было передавать id итема, код выше